# Instantiated interface object - How?

Tags: java, android, oop, cursor, wrapper

Ran into this line of code that defines a variable of type Cursor - an interface - in a class - CursorWrapper - that implements the interface:

```
protected final Cursor mCursor;
```

Then this is the constructor for the class:

```
public CursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) { mCursor = cursor; }
```

What is going on here? It seems like an interface is being instantiated, but I thought you couldn't instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 1):

> What is going on here?

Um, `CursorWrapper` is accepting an object of type `Cursor` as a constructor parameter, then assigning it to a field.

> It seems like an interface is being instantiated

Neither of your statements are instantiating anything.

> but I thought you couldn't instantiate an interface

You can't. You can instantiate a class that implements the interface.

---

`CursorWrapper` wraps a `Cursor`. `Cursor` is an interface. There are several classes that implement `Cursor`. Developers get a `Cursor` from a few places, mostly from database queries and `ContentResolver` queries.

However, like [the honey badger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crazy_Nastyass_Honey_Badger#Honey_Badger_Don.27t_Care), `CursorWrapper` don't care. `CursorWrapper` will happily wrap any `Cursor` implementation. `CursorWrapper` on its own is fairly useless; it is designed to make it easier to create custom wrappers by subclassing `CursorWrapper`, as I did with [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/blob/master/provider/src/com/commonsware/cwac/provider/LegacyCompatCursorWrapper.java).

Now, if `CursorWrapper` could only wrap a `Cursor` that came from a database, then it should not take a `Cursor` as a parameter, but rather a `SQLiteCursor`.

Comment: Ok, not instantiating, assigning a value to the Cursor variable. I don't get how you can even create a Cursor variable if Cursor is an interface, let alone assign it a value. And, if there is nothing being instantiated, what is the point of assigning mCursor to cursor if cursor is just another reference variable, not pointing to any object.